# Using same React component in a SharePoint webpart

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-2013

I am building a react component.

Index .html looks like:

```
<div id="**app1**"></div>
```

Index.js looks like this:

```
render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('**app1**')
);
```

Now, I have a content editor webpart on sharepoint and I refer to this index.html file.

Next, I want to add another content editor referring to same html file, but only one displays the data.

The problem is I want to export react component bundled in Sharepoint webpart so that I can use it multiple times on the same page. 
But in order to render it to dom,, how to get the unique id of the webpart?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Sharing it here.

Create a function in your index.js file of react application. Then, add this function in window object.

Now this function will be available in ascx control of SharePoint webpart. Call this function with parameters, where one of the parameter will be the SharePoint webpart client id.

In the index.js function, add the render method to render the react component in this id received from the function parameter.

Hope this will help others.